# Parameters wp_nav_menu() are not working correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

It seems that the issue lies in the behavior of the parameters for the wp_nav_menu() function. For instance:

```
<?php 
  wp_nav_menu( [
  'theme_location'  => 'menu-header',
  'container'       => false,
  'menu_class'      => 'menu__list',
  'menu_id'         => false,
  'echo'            => true,
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  ] );
?>
```

With these specified parameters, the container strangely doesn't disable. However, if I write, for example, 'nav', the container tag changes. Additionally, `'menu_class' => 'menu__list'` changes the class not for the `<ul>` tag but for the container...

This is how the menu is registered:

```
function test_menus(){

  $locations = array(
    'menu-header' => __('Header Menu', 'test'),
    'menu-footer' => __('Footer Menu', 'test')
  );

  register_nav_menus($locations);
}

add_action( 'init','test_menus');
```

Comment: Sometimes, conflicts with other plugins or themes can cause unexpected behavior. Temporarily deactivate other plugins or switch to a default theme to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score -3):

This code looks correct and registers two navigation menus: 'Header Menu' and 'Footer Menu' with the theme. Make sure you're using the correct theme locations when calling wp_nav_menu(), matching the keys in the $locations array.

If you're still encountering issues with the wp_nav_menu() function not behaving as expected, you may need to carefully review your theme files, especially the header and footer templates, to ensure there are no conflicting modifications or overrides

Comment: Did you create this "answer" with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)? (This doesn't even attempt to solve this issue)